# Получение токена группы VK для загрузки клипа с помощью архивного метода

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, post, authenticationtoken

Делаю скриптик для автоматической загрузки клипов, нашел решение для залива в клипы конкретного аккаунта с помощью токена, полученного при авторизации VK ME по следующей ссылке:

> https://oauth.vk.com/token?
>
> grant_type=password&
>
> client_id=6146827&
>
> client_secret=qVxWRF1CwHERuIrKBnqe&
>
> username=ACCOUNT&
>
> password=PASSWORD&
>
> v=5.131&
>
> 2fa_supported=1

Где `ACCOUNT` и `PASSWORD` в моем случае - это номер телефона, прикрепленный к аккаунту и пароль соответственно. При попытке использовать токен, полученный любым другим образом, сталкиваюсь с ответом `Unknown method passed` от сервера. Подскажите, пожалуйста как можно получить рабочий токен для сообщества!

Скрипт для загрузки клипа от имени пользователя ([источник](https://zelenka.guru/threads/2473585/?pget=1)):

```
import requests
from os.path import getsize
import random
import string
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
filename = "video.mp4"  #  путь к видео
token = "ВАШ_ТОКЕН"
description = "Описание и хэштеги"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.post("https://api.vk.com/method/shortVideo.create", data=dict(v=5.132,
                                                                               wallpost=1,
                                                                               description=description,
                                                                               file_size=getsize(filename),
                                                                               access_token=token))
    upload_url = r.json()["response"]["upload_url"]
    fields = {
        'file': ('untitiled.mp4', open(filename, "rb"), "video/mp4"),
    }
    boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 16))
    m = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields, boundary=boundary)
    r = requests.post(upload_url, data=m,
                      headers={"user-agent": "vk-test-clip-upload 1", "Content-Type": m.content_type})
    print(r.status_code, r.text)
```